# What are the criteria to state equality of iterated integration?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there any criterion to state that:

$\int(\int f(x,y)dx)dy = \int(\int f(x,y)dy)dx  $   ?

I guess that it holds when both $\int f(x,y)dx$ and $\int f(x,y)dy$ exists. Is it right? is there any other criterion?

Comment: Fubini's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't remember the existence of this theorem.

Comment: I have forgotten C, only remembered bit and part from your username!